A "finite" property in the locally compact Hausdorff space
I'm working on following exercises:
Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and the intersection a set of compact subset $\{A_i\}$ is contained in an open subset $U$. Then there exists finitely many $A_i$ such that their intersection is contained in $U$. 
My idea is that tried to find a finite cover of $U^c$ of the open cover $\{A_i\}$. Then I'm stuck since there seems not a conclusion that guarantee the compactness of closed set $U^c$ in locally compact space. So my question is firstly is this conclusion right? Secondly will my idea about the proof work?

$\bigcap (A_i\cap U^{c})=\emptyset$ and $ A_i\cap U^{c}$ is compact for each $i$.

@geetha290krm Why not an official answer? And it seems that local compactness is not needed.

This result is true in any Hausdorff space. Local compactness is not needed.
Even with Local compactness you cannot prove that $U^{c}$ is compact, so your idea does not work.
$A_i\cap U^{c}$ is a closed subset of the compact set $A_i$ and hence it is compact. Call it $K_i$. Then $\bigcap K_i=(\bigcap A_i) \cap U^{c}=\emptyset$ by hypothesis. Now, for any fixed index $i_0$ we have $K_{i_0}\subseteq \bigcup_{i \neq i_0} K_i^{c}$. This gives an open cover of $K_{i_0}$ and it has finite subcover. I will let you finish the proof here.
